# Disable / Enable Button, VOTE APK

Tags: java, android

that is my first question! I would be happy if someone could help me.

I am creating an APK in the studio that calculates vote.

He's like at the moment:

```
int afavor = 0;
int contra = 0;
int naosei = 0;
int whereVote=-1, CONTRA_VOTE=1, FAVOR_VOTE=2, NAOSEI_VOTE=3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


public void resultado(View view) {
    String resultado = (contra) + (naosei) + (afavor) + " Votos";
    totalvotos(resultado);

}

private void totalvotos(String message) {
    TextView parcialTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parcial);
    parcialTextView.setText(message);
}


public void contra(View view) {
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bcontra);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bafavor);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnaosei);

    button1.setEnabled(false);
    button2.setEnabled(true);
    button3.setEnabled(true);


    switch(whereVote){
        case FAVOR_VOTE: afavor--; break;
        case NAOSEI_VOTE: naosei--; break;
        default: break;
    }
    whereVote=CONTRA_VOTE;


    contra = contra + 1;
    display1(contra);
}


public void afavor(View view) {
    afavor = afavor + 1;
    display1(afavor);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bafavor);
    button.setEnabled(false);
}

public void naosei(View view) {
    naosei = naosei + 1;
    display2(naosei);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnaosei);
    button.setEnabled(false);
}




private void display(int number) {
    TextView contraTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.contra);
    contraTextView.setText("" + number);
}

private void display1(int number) {
    TextView afavorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.afavor);
    afavorTextView.setText("" + number);
}
private void display2(int number) {

    TextView naoseiTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.naosei);
    naoseiTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

}

A diagram done in Word, which drew my idea'm attached.

the important thing is that whenever the user changes the vote, the new voting button disables the old vote of the button will be enabled, and the vote is taken out of the old vote and passed to the new vote.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_zCSFabSj-UkU4YjlaYUZWMEE/view

Ty for any future answers =]

@Edit

I got that erro: Error:

(46, 18) error: constant expression required
(47, 18) error: constant expression required

```
case FAVOR_VOTE: afavor--; break;
case NAOSEI_VOTE: naosei--; break;
```

Whats worong BlueMoon93?

Comment: Using function and variable names such as 'afavor' and 'naosei' isn't a good practice. Foreigners will have a lot of trouble trying to understand your code, even if it looks natural to you.

Comment: Use boolean for enable disable button

Comment: Updated the code to relfect your progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `afavor`, `contra` and `naosei` functions, you will need to set the corresponding button's `enable` property to `false`, and the remainder buttons to `true`.

Then, you also check whether the user already voted in the current page, using an integer, for example. `-1` for 'not voted yet', `2` for 'afavor', `1` for 'contra' and `3` for 'naosei'. On these functions, you check whether this integer is 'not voted yet': if it's not, subtract a vote from the corresponding counter. After this, set it to the pressed button's code.

Globally:

```
int whereVote=-1;
final int CONTRA_VOTE=1, FAVOR_VOTE=2, NAOSEI_VOTE=3;
```

Example for 'contra' button:

```
// Get buttons
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bcontra);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bafavor);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnaosei);

// Enable or disable buttons
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);

// subtract a vote (if needed)
switch(whereVote){
    case FAVOR_VOTE: afavor--; break;
    //case CONTRA_VOTE: contra--; break;
    case NAOSEI_VOTE: naosei--; break;
    default: break;
}
whereVote=CONTRA_VOTE;   

// increase vote
contra = contra + 1;
display1(contra);
```

Comment: Updated CONTRA_VOTE, FAVOR_VOTE and NAOSEI_VOTE declaration.